# channel consume order in different goroutine

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                fmt.Println("here")
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        q := time.NewTimer(time.Second)
        <-q.C
        done <- true
    }()

    <-done
    fmt.Println("closing")
}
```

My question is if `done` channel is consumed by goroutine not main goroutine.
the program will be blocked.

But the fact is that the program never be blocked.main goroutine seem to be consumed the `done` channel everytime.

Why?

Comment: If multiple receivers are ready to receive, you can't predict which one of them receives a value. Eventually it will be main's turn. What you see works as expected.

Comment: @Peter Since we can't predict which one of them receives, main goroutine may be blocked by sub goroutine receives the value

Answer (score 0):

Although, I didn't found answer in docs, looks like receives value the routine which first tried to read from the channel. In our case, always `main` method is almost always reaching `<-done` (99.0%), because routines starts asynchronous and takes a while to run. But anyway, I would strongly suggest you do not rely on this, as this is not a guaranteed.

To demonstrate it, look at the following example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)

    n := 5

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            fmt.Println(i, "Waiting to read")
            <-done
            fmt.Println(i, "DONE")
        }(i)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    for i := 0 ; i < n; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        done <- true
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

Which will produce output

```
0 Waiting to read
1 Waiting to read
2 Waiting to read
3 Waiting to read
4 Waiting to read
0 DONE
1 DONE
2 DONE
3 DONE
4 DONE
```